# How To Display WikiText

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki

I would like to fetch the WikiText from a Wikipedia page and display it in a browser using Javascript. The following is what I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wikiInfo">&nbsp;</div>

  <script>
    $.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Dog&callback=?',
         function(data) {
           $("div").add(data);
           alert('load performed');
   });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Eventually, I would like to be able to save the fetched wikitext to a variable as well, so any help on that would be appreciated too.

Comment: What do you want different? You could use `.html()` instead of `.add()`

Comment: I suppose I should mention that it doesn't work. :) Does it work for you?

Comment: You are likely having cross-domain issues then. You need to create a proxy script on your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is cross domain, so it doesn't work... make a wiki.php and fetch "wiki.php?title=Dog" with JS...

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

$title = $_GET["title"];

echo curl("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&callback=?&titles=$title");
```

Edited using @Tgr WikiPedia link. I also suggest parsing JSON in PHP and then outputing HTML or raw text.

Comment: How would I then modify my original code to use this? I simply changed the uri param of my .get to "wiki.php?title=Dog", but I'm still not seeing anything...

Comment: Your WP link was bad (I edited code using link provided by Tgr, make sure you have `/wiki.php?title=Dog` (with slash) and PHP file in your root folder, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

`action=raw` does not accept JSONP callback parameters. You should do proper API calls:

```
$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?'+
     'action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content'+
     '&format=json&callback=?&titles=Dog', 
     function(result) { /* process JSON result */ });
```

See [API documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery_-_Properties#revisions_.2F_rv) (also [this remark](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aData_formats#JSON_callback_restrictions) about JSONP restrictions), a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jVcJd/) and the Wikipedia articles about [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to understand why your first approach didn't work.

You can study the format of the API results by replacing 'json' with 'jsonfm': http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&titles=Dog

Comment: I copied that string straight from the MediaWiki api site. :) But noted.

Comment: @allie: using action=raw is much simpler, as long as you call it from PHP or something similar. In javascript, cross-domain calls are more trouble: you need either a proper JSONP formatted reply, or CORS permission headers, or you have to set up some sort of gateway. MediaWiki supports CORS headers, but they are disabled on Wikipedia, so you are left with JSONP and the API, or a gateway on your own server.